# How to change default URL address

Tags: graphdb

the default url address of the workbench is http://localhost:7200
I want to change it to this: http://localhost:7200/graphdb

Is it possible? How can I configure it?

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the question, it's not clear what's the motivation to run the GraphDB under a different URL address. The short answer is you cannot do this. A hack, which is not guaranteed to work in the next future versions is to use the deprecated generate war script from an older [distribution](http://maven.ontotext.com/content/groups/all-onto/com/ontotext/graphdb/graphdb-ee/8.0.0/graphdb-ee-8.0.0-dist.zip). After downloading the link, copy the file `bin/generate-war-files` to your current version and execute it. The generated WAR file may be deployed in Apache Tomcat name under whatever name you want.